# How to mutate i variable in "for loop" in swift

Tags: java, ios, swift, for-loop

Hi am trying to execute this Java Code in swift. In Java the code is:

```
public class Test{

 public static void main(String []args){
    int[] arr = new int[6];
    arr[0] = 0;
    arr[1] = 1;
    arr[2] = 2;
    arr[3] = 3;
    arr[4] = 4;
    arr[5] = 5;
    for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
    System.out.println("i="+i);
    if(arr[i] % 2 == 0) continue;
    arr[i] = arr[i] + 1;
    i--;
    }
 }
```

}

And the Console output is:

> i=0
>   i=1
>   i=1
>   i=2
>   i=3
>   i=3
>   i=4
>   i=5
>   i=5

The same code in Swift is

```
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
for var i in 0...5 {
    print("i=\(i)")
    if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {continue}
    arr[i] += 1
    i = i-1
}
```

And in Swift code the output is:

> i=0
>   i=1 
>   i=2
>   i=3
>   i=4
>   i=5

And the problem is that even that compiler force me to set i as var to compile, the value of i does not mutate in loop and the i gets every time the values 0...5 as set.

My question is **How can I write the Java Code in Swift so I can mutate the i when I want**.

Comment: As the linked Q&A says, even if you mark the loop variable mutable, the value you are mutating will be a local copy and not the actual loop variable. Mutating the loop variable in a `for...in` loop is a very bad idea, hence Swift doesn't allow it. You should redefine your code to avoid it in the first place rather than trying to translate a Java code line-by-line.

Comment: Modifying the loop variable inside the loop is often bad practice. You could achieve the same effect with (for example) `if (arr[i] % 2 != 0) { arr[i] = arr[i] + 1; }` and that would translate directly to Swift.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I don't think it's a correct duplicate. While the current dupe target provides insight into why marking as `var` doesn't work, this question is about mutating the loop variable _to change how the loop behaves_.

Answer (score 3):

Use a while loop:

```
var i = 0
while i <= 5 {
    print("i=\(i)")
    if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
        i += 1
        continue
    }
    arr[i] += 1
}
```

Note the second change: Instead of subtracting 1 from `i` at the end, you only add 1 to `i` when you continue the loop, because in a while loop, `i` normally does not change.